# Passing variable arguments to a C program from command line

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

```
/* test1.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int m = 11;
    system("./test2 m");
    return 0;
}
```

The above program prints 0, whereas I expect it to print 11.

```
/* test2.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int m = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%d\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone provide an explanation? Also what would be the right way in order to print the desired 11?

Comment: It's your own fault to refuse to check whether the integer parsing succeeded. Making blind assumptions at every step is not the way to write programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system() function just takes a string as its argument. It doesn't know that you have a variable named `m` and that it should substitute that variable in the string (Which would not be possible in C anyways with such a syntax.)

That means you are executing your second program like this:

```
 ./test2 m
```

Your 2 program does `atoi(argv[1]);` , which will then be the same as `atoi("m");` , which makes atoi() return 0.

You need to build up the string you want system() to execute

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char command[128];
    int m = 11;
    sprintf(command , "./test2 %d", m);
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the character `m` to the command line, not its value.

Answer (score 3):

C does not expand variables in string constants like perl so `m` in your command string is a string constant.

What you need to do is print the value of `m`to the command string:

```
/* test1.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int m = 11;
    char buf[100];
    sprintf(buf, "./test2 %d", m);
    system(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Funny how we came to the same solution here, y? But you forgot `int` before `m` ;)

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was that I assumed test1.c was compiling, so I didn't scan for syntax errors.
And not strange at all that they are the same, because it is the simplest and most straightforward solution.

Comment: I have this thread running in my head which scans for syntax errors all the time. Stops working about 2am, though.

Comment: I let the compiler do that, so my cores can focus all their processing cycles on semantic errors.